# Re-organize a javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array of question and different answers (which I build dynamically, so the number of entries and different answers can vary):

```
var qaArray = [
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer A"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer C"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer A"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer C"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer A"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
]
```

I need a function to build another array object from this, which would hold the 'answer' and 'count', in this case it would be:

```
[
    { answer: "Answer A", count: 3 },
    { answer: "Answer B", count: 4 },
    { answer: "Answer C", count: 2 },
]
```

Is there an easy method to do this, without straight forward loops?

Comment: I will recommend you to use `lodash` here and use `groupBy` to perform it easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ES6 is not a problem, it can be done by:

```js
var qaArray = [
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer A"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer C"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer A"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer C"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer A"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
];

var result = [...new Set(qaArray.map(q => q.answer))].map(a => ({ answer: a, count: qaArray.filter(e => e.answer === a).length }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for solution without `reduce` or `forEach`, here is a verbose way using [lodash](http://lodash.com).

`_.countBy` will give you close result, but if you want to transform it into array as you want, use `mapValues`.

```
_.chain(qaArray)
.countBy('answer')
.mapValues(function(value, key) {
  return { answer: key, count: value }
})
.values()
.value()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` for this. Concept is to push element to accumulator if it doesn't exist and increment the `count` if it does.

Please find below solution

```js
var qaArray = [
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer A"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer C"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer A"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer C"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer A"},
    { question: "Question", answer: "Answer B"},
]


result = qaArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
  var exist = acc.find(x => x.answer === item.answer);
  if (exist) {
    exist.count += 1;
  } else {
    acc.push({
      answer: item.answer,
      count: 1
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, []);


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` to key your answers then `reduce` over the data to get counts, like so:

```
var result = Array.from(qaArray.reduce((acc, { answer }) => {
  const current = acc.get(answer) || { answer, count: 0 };
  current.count++;
  return acc.set(answer, current);
}, new Map()).values());

console.log(result);
```